# React JS 2 different Router to same Path

Tags: reactjs, web, navbar, router

I have a website with a navbar like that: Home|Shop|About.
But I want a link on my Home page that opens also the same shop page as the navbar.

How can I implement two Routers that leads to the same Page?

Comment: Can please show us the  sample of the code that you have tried .

Answer (score 0):

Simply setup for two Routers Path use one Component.
Best wishes!!